# How to use vue libraries in django templates

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-templates, frontend

In my project I am using django templates and include vue as script:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Now I want to use some vue libraries that can be installed with npm. Question is, how to use these libraries in my project? Please, give some examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install both Vue.js and the libraries via **NPM** and then import them in a JS file that gets bundled/compiled by **Webpack**. Then have the **Django Webpack Loader** package render the JS file in your template: *https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader*